# How do I convert a Infopath form created in sharepoint to Word

Tags: infopath, form

How do I convert a Infopath form that I created in sharepoint to Word

Thanks

Comment: As I said on SO : I'm not an expert with Word development, but I think you should either choose InfoPath and publish forms in InfoPath format (using the rich client or Infopath Form Services) or choose directly Word and develop the form in Word. There is no magic button that will magically bridge the two world. Code can do that, but it's not trivial.

Comment: SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302063/how-to-convert-infopath-form-created-in-sharepoint-2010-to-word-2010

Comment: -1 Infopath form is created in Infopath Designer and can be used by/in Sharepoint services, servers, etc. but the phrase "a Infopath form that I created in sharepoint" is senseless to me. Infopath Designer is part of MS Office pack, so the answer is obvious. I do not see here even the question

Comment: I tried the above 4 step solution; however, when I opened the .MHT file it was scrambled with graphics and only a small amount of text. Is there any simple way (no coding or third party software) to convert a 2013 web-based InfoPath to a MS Word or PDF document. It seems these solutions are referring to features in the "Filler" forms and not "web based"? Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the IP form you created.
2. Copy the form.
3. Paste the form into a new word document.

Answer (score 0):

I have to make  some assumptions here as the question does not go into much detail. I assume you want to automate the conversion from InfoPath to MS-Word whenever a new form is saved in a Document or Form Library, which is a common requirement as it makes it easier to distribute the file to people who don't have InfoPath installed or who don't have access to the underlying XSN file.

There are a number of approaches you can take, the most obvious ones are:

1. Create an Event Receiver in C# / vb.net that reads the data out  of the XML file and programmatically merge this data into an MS-Word template using Microsoft's  free OpenXML libraries.
2. Use a third party tool for converting InfoPath to MS-Word, Excel or PDF. [See this example](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2012/02/convert-infopath-to-ms-word-excel-xps.html). (Disclaimer, I wrote this post so consider me biased)

Answer (score 0):

In the InfoPath form follow the next steps:

A)File
B)Save&Send
C)Export to Web -This will save the file as a .mht file.
D)Right click the .mht file and open with word.